# Why do diplexer low-pass filter output have more inductors than capacitors and vice versa?

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, low-pass, high-pass-filter

I am reading  "Practical Radio Frequency Test & Measurement A Technician's Handbook" by Joseph J. Carr. On page 41, it has a diagram (figure 2.29 shown below). In that figure, why do diplexer low-pass filter output has more inductors than capacitors and vice versa?

[image]

Comment: It's the behavior around the region of resonance that is driving this choice, I believe, coupled with assumptions of the source driving impedance and the load impedance on the other end. (Probably low source impedance and light load.) I don't know what's on each end of these, but I've plotted these in the past in specific cases and the T-approach had a very nice smooth response without peaking by comparison. But it's been a while. I'd need to reconstruct that effort to be sure my memory is accurate, now.

Answer (score 2):

A low-high diplexer consists of a low-pass filter and a high-pass filter as shown.  The low-pass is an LC ladder and can be achieved in two ways - with a leading series-L or a leading shunt-C.  These have differing input impedances at high frequencies, the series-L goes to an open circuit, the shunt-C to a short circuit.  If you are going to connect it in parallel with another filter to make a diplexer, you want it to go open, hence the low-pass filter starts with a series-L.  Similarly, the high-pass filter starts with a series-C so it goes open at low frequencies.

Given this, if you choose odd-order filters for your low and high pass, then with the requirement of a leading series L in he low pass and leading series C in the high pass, you get more inductors in the low pass and more capacitors in the high pass.  If you chose even order filters this wouldn't happen, and you would have an extra shunt C at the output of the low-pass, and an extra shunt L at the output of the high pass.

Answer (score 1):

A *diplexer* is kind of the opposite of a bandpass.

- bandpass: low-pass and high-pass have overlap, input/output is combined
- diplexer: low-pass and high-pass don't overlap, input/output is separated

If a diplexer's I/O were combined, it would be a a kind of *band stop* filter.

Remember that for a given filter order, the basic difference between a low pass and high pass is to swap the inductors and capacitors. In this case, what's shown are a pair of *5th-order* filters, one low-pass and one high-pass. The low-pass will have series inductors and parallel caps, the high pass series caps and parallel inductors. So the low-pass is 3 inductors + 2 capacitors, while high-pass swaps the L and C and so has 2 inductors and 3 capacitors.

As far as the exact response, each filter can be tuned for maximal passband flatness (e.g., Bessel, Butterworth) or maximum roll-off (e.g., Chebyshev, elliptcal/Cauer). Not sure what they chose here without having a look at a simulation.

This kind of passive diplexer filter is interesting in that it can work in *both* directions. An example is the diplexer used for DOCSIS cable modems, which uses low-band (5 ~ 42MHz) for upstream and higher band (>54 MHz) for downstream. Another kind of cable diplexer divides cable TV and MoCA signals.

Comment: The bandstop idea is nice but ideally extremely high Q and sensitive to component tolerance errors , must be designed for low very Q (Bessel) with an  offset error spec

Answer (score 1):

For the frequency range being considered, it is safe to assume that the filters will drive a 50 ohm load. Thus, for the low pass filter, the combination of the last inductor and the load provides additional filtering. In the same way, for the high pass filter, the combination of the last capacitor and the load provides additional filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Each are odd-order filters with conjugate (complementary or mirror image) matched-impedance filters. When  loaded with rated R  on the output, the filter has good return loss over the entire band.

With this filter, you could drive with a voltage source with 0 loss if the load is well-matched and get a flat response. But if the load is mismatched, then using the rated source impedance reduces the ripple with -6 dB loss.